# Should the entire project be compliant with PSR-0

Tags: php, psr-0

Is PSR-0 suppose to be able autoload any classes or just libraries/external api:s?

Example structure on a MVC compliant with PSR-0

```
Application
  Controller
     TestController.php
  Model
  View
  Library
System
  ...
```

TestController.php

```
<?php
namespace Application/Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
}
```

... Or just a custom autoloader for controllers, models etc...?

Answer (score 0):

According to Phil Sturgeon (whose claims to fame include writing the [PHP-FIG FAQ](http://www.php-fig.org/faq/)):

> Are you trying to make your entire application PSR-0, because it
>   should only be generic code packages that you do this with

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/04/is-psr0-shortsighted-or-are-you

So it would seem the answer is no, PSR-0 is not designed to be used for an entire web application, but for packages or libraries that you intend to publish for other developers to include in their projects.